# Can I get an EASA class 1 medical if I am red/green color blind?

Tags: easa-regulations, medical

When I got the Class 2 certificate(one week ago), AME told me that I am red/green color blind and the certificate is valid by day only. Is it possible for me to pursue an aviation career and pass the Class 1 certificate?

I failed almost all red/green Ishihara plates. I heard something about a test called CAD, and if I pass this test I can continue but im not sure.

Comment: There may not be a reason that the FAA cannot issue you a first class medical certificate, unless the AME told you on the spot that they could not because of color blindness. It’s possible that An AME still can but with a similar restriction.  This is really more of a question for an AME.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what ways is color blindness an issue in modern jet airliners?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16630/in-what-ways-is-color-blindness-an-issue-in-modern-jet-airliners)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an applicant failing the Ishihara test, the next step is a medical assessor. If they're deemed "colour safe" *(defined below),* they can get Class 1 medical.

In your case, presumably, you were not deemed colour safe since you're daytime-only Class 2, if that's indeed the case, then unfortunately Class 1 will not be possible according to the EASA regulations below:

> **MED.B.075 Colour vision**
>
> (a) Applicants shall be assessed as unfit, where they cannot
> demonstrate their ability to readily perceive the colours that are
> necessary for the safe exercise of the privileges of the licence.
>
> (b) *Examination and assessment*
>
> 1. Applicants shall be subjected to the Ishihara test for the initial issue of a medical certificate. Applicants who pass that test may be
>    assessed as fit.
> 2. For a class 1 medical certificate:
>
>    1. Applicants who do not pass the Ishihara test shall be referred to the medical assessor of the licensing authority and shall undergo
>       further colour perception testing to establish whether they are colour
>       safe.
>    2. Applicants shall be normal trichromats or shall be colour safe.
>    3. Applicants who fail further colour perception testing shall be assessed as unfit.
> 3. For a class 2 medical certificate:
>
>    1. Applicants who do not pass the Ishihara test shall undergo further colour perception testing to establish whether they are colour safe.
>    2. Applicants who do not have satisfactory perception of colours shall be limited to exercising the privileges of the applicable licence in
>       daytime only.
>
> — [Commission Regulation (EU) No 1178/2011](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg/2011/1178/2021-01-12)

"Colour safe" from the same source means:

> ... the ability of an applicant to readily distinguish the colours used in air navigation and to correctly identify aviation coloured lights.

Comment: I only did the Ishihara test that I failed, AME didn't say something else about other tests to see if I am color safe.

Comment: @Grey: This is good news then! Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I don't have any links or documentation for this. This is just what an instructor at my flight school said, so take it with a grain of salt.

The only reason a pilot would need color vision is because towers use a red/green/white light gun to communicate with planes that have lost their radio. So, you need to have just enough color vision to be able to tell the difference between the red and green signals. The instructor has to take their color-blind student out to the apron of a towered airport and have the tower shine red and green signals at them, and if they can tell the difference, they're good to go.

Comment: I can see red and green properly, the only thing is that I can't pass Ishihara plates test and this is why I have night restriction.

Comment: You also need red white color acuity at night in order to accurately judge the orientation of another aircraft in flight.

Comment: @CarloFelicione Differentiating between white and colored light is a lot easier than differentiating between two different colors, so I presume the assumption is that, if you can tell red from green, you can tell red from white. But, like I said, I'm just repeating what I've heard, it's possible I'm completely off-base here.

Answer (score 0):

To start with the same disclaimer, I don't have any documentation on this, but as far as I recall, there are glasses available that enhance the ability to tell the difference between red and green by means of filters and those are valid for driving a car in night traffic. Again, a test will have to prove your ability to work with them, but if you pass that test, you're in. 20/20 Vision is not even a demand for military pilots.

Comment: Color blindness is not a restriction on driving any type of road vehicle in the UK. In fact "green" lights in the UK are actually a blue-green color, as an aid for color-blind drivers.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different tests for color blindness. Ishihara plates are the cheapest but notorious for poor accuracy: if you don’t pass (and many people don’t), that isn’t really a failure; it just means you need a more accurate test.

What other tests are acceptable likely varies by country, but if you can tell red and green traffic lights apart (by color, not by position), then you should be able to pass one of the better tests and get the restriction removed from your medical certificate.

Answer (score 0):

as one of the answers already mentioned reference to «MED.B.075 Colour vision» paragraph of 1178/2011, I won't paste it here again. That is the important piece of legal poetry that makes decision whether you fly at night or not. Or whether you get class 1 medical or not.

Important part is, there is no «color blind» terminology in EASA legislation today. There is «color safe» instead, as it was again mentioned before here in this topic. If you fail Ishihara test (like I did), you either accept your fate by confessing that you are not color safe, or you demand more sophisticated research. I was told by medical practitioner that Ishihara test does not show how severe your red or green deficiency is, it just exposes that such condition exists.

CAD test, being on top of «being very intelligent, super-duper piece of software that is impossible to fool because it is so clever and so many man-years of scientific effort has been put into it»-kind of hype, on the other hand, can show severity of condition somewhat reliably (as they say). There is a certain threshold, degree of deficiency that is acceptable for class 1 medical or class 2 night rating. I failed to resolve 4 Ishihara plates and failed CAD test miserably. Alas, nighttime is sleep time for me :) On the other hand, I have heard of folks that failed Ishihara but passed anomaloscope (see below) and won the class 1 medical prize.

Besides CAD test, you can choose to do a latern test or anomaloscope, which are older tests but still acceptable by authorities AFAIK. I don't remember by heart, but some exotic scrutiny exists in addition to these three. Being successful with any of the above, you get an override of your failed Ishihara test with positive outcome.

All said above applies to EASA jurisdiction.

Some countries have totally different set of rules. US has SODA that can potentially make your life much easier, granted that you actually *resolve* the colors that are actually *needed* at nighttime (e.g. you actually see that runway threshold is green and those beacons over there are red etc). Australia is very liberal in this regard and allows color blind people do more in aviation than any other state on this planet.