# Can a colour blind person pursue a career in Commercial Flying?

Tags: commercial-aviation, pilots, medical, regulations

I have been an ardent aviation geek since childhood and always wanted to be flying commercially. But sometime later during a medical examination through Ishihara plates test I learned that I am color blind. I have been reading quite a lot about colour blind people are considered to be medically unfit to fly. So I just wanted to confirm if this is true or should I go and take some additional test before I let go of my dream.

Comment: Are you red/green, blue/yellow, or total?

Comment: Also: [Why do some air forces no allow color blind pilots](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16098/why-do-some-air-forces-not-allow-color-blind-pilots).

Comment: If you want details on the regulations or specific medical requirements then you should mention which country or jurisdiction you're interested in. But there are different types of color blindness and it may not be possible to give a definite answer; only an aviation medical examiner can give you precise information about your personal situation.

Comment: Note that the first linked question and answer are written by retired colour-blind B747 captain. And it states the condition under which it is possible.